# how can i get all inputs excluding buttons and hidden fields with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I've got the following which will excludes all buttons, but how can I also exclude hidden fields?

```
$("#selector").find(":input:not(:button)").each(function (i) { // do something
```

I'm sure this is probably simple, I just can't find it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

the following code should do it..

```
$('#selector :input').not(':button,:hidden').each(...);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#selector').find('input').not(':button').not('input[type=hidden]').each(function(i) {
});
```

should do it.
I'm not sure if this one

```
$('#selector').find('input').not(':button').not(':hidden').each(function(i) {
});
```

also works for that purpose, but its worth a try.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#selector :input:not(:button, :hidden)").each(function (i) { // do something
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, (jquery 2.2.0)

**DID NOT WORK**

```
$('#signup-form :input:not(:hidden :button)').each(function(){
$('#signup-form :input').not(':hidden :button').each(function(){
$('#signup-form *').filter(':input:not([type=hidden][type=button])').each(function(){
```

**DID**

```
$('#signup-form *').filter(':input').not(':button').not('input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
```

OR

```
$('#signup-form :input').not(':hidden').not(':button').each(function(){
```