# How to apply bootstrap css to all buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and what I want to is apply this css to all my buttons. I tried some code but none of worked for me. By the way I don't want to add class attribute to all my buttons. Is there any way to do this?

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] { 
     //Apply Bootstrap button css here!
}
```

Comment: Just define it at the end! And or add this `!important`

Comment: Just copy/paste the same styles ? This is a real useless question....

Comment: Curious how *I tried some code but none of worked for me.* (and none of the attempts showed) is becoming a very common phrase on code-for-me questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $.find(":button").each(function (i) {
           //Apply bootstarp to i here
      }
   });
</script>
```

Get more ideas here: [how can i get all inputs excluding buttons and hidden fields with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990227/how-can-i-get-all-inputs-excluding-buttons-and-hidden-fields-with-jquery)

Comment: The OP wants to change the CSS of `input[type="button"]` and `input[type="submit"]`. You're providing a JS code which doesn't do much.

Comment: @WissamEl-Kik How would you define "doesn't do much" ?? It can change the css properties of all the buttons. Exactly the operation the guy wants to perform.

Comment: The script you provided doesn't change any CSS value. It's just a useless JS loop. The OP wants to change the "design" of the buttons and the answer you provided doesn't do that. Try running your code and let me know if it changes anything in the HTML DOM.

Comment: @WissamEl-Kik my comment `//Apply bootstarp to i here` means you can do something like `$(i).css('color', 'black');` ... so basically whatever you want to do. Check http://api.jquery.com/css/ , its cool!

Comment: Still it doesn't solve the OP's issue. He needs the "design" of the Bootstrap buttons for his 2 input buttons. If you're about to write a hundred line of JS to apply the "exact" layout, then do it. Otherwise, this loop is useless. On another hand, `$(i)` is useless too, because `i` is the index, it's not a selector. The jQuery object needs a selector as first param.

Comment: @WissamEl-Kik How come it does not solve the issue? Yeah `i` is the index, sorry for that. Just use the index properly and you can change the property of `css`, change the `class` OR apply `style`. I am pretty sure the guy is just asking about changing the class attribute of the button. You mind reading the question once again please? About the lines of code, have you actually read my answer? Does it look like `thousand`? I solved the issue with JS in 7 lines, you have to write 75 + 32 lines for every color. Where exactly is the `thousand` lines you are talking mate?

Comment: You still didn't provided the answer and the OP didn't mentioned that he needs a jQuery solution. The question is tagged with "css" and "twitter-bootstrap". The OP mentioned that he needs a CSS solution. End of debate.

Comment: Lol…  You cant end the debate by making things up. Tags does not limit it to css. The question says `Is there any way to do this?` do i really need to quote fron the question again and again? Btw, can you please quote from the question where he says he does not want jquery and he ONLY css? If he really did not wanted this why did he chose my answer? So my answer is really what the guy asked, lets end the debate here :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about these buttons:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

You can have the same CSS design, if you use the `.btn` CSS class on the input fields. This is the right method to achieve what you're looking for.

In case you don't want to apply a CSS class to the input fields, here's the CSS code:

```
input[type="button"], 
input[type="submit"] {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
input[type="button"]:focus, 
input[type="button"]:active, 
input[type="button"]:active:focus, 
input[type="submit"]:focus, 
input[type="submit"]:active, 
input[type="submit"]:active:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
input[type="button"]:focus, 
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:focus, 
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active {
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125) inset;
    outline: 0 none;
}
input[type="button"][disabled],
input[type="submit"][disabled] {
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.65;
    pointer-events: none;
}
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
    color: #333;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
    color: #333;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active {
    background-image: none;
}
input[type="button"][disabled]:active, 
input[type="button"][disabled]:focus, 
input[type="button"][disabled]:hover, 
input[type="submit"][disabled]:active, 
input[type="submit"][disabled]:focus, 
input[type="submit"][disabled]:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

Then if you want the blue color, you need to add the following:

```
/* Blue */
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color:#337ab7;
    border-color:#2e6da4;
    color:#fff;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:hover, {
    background-color:#286090;
    border-color:#204d74;
    color:#fff;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active {
    background-image: none;
}
input[type="button"][disabled],
input[type="button"][disabled]:active,
input[type="button"][disabled]:focus,
input[type="button"][disabled]:hover,
input[type="submit"][disabled],
input[type="submit"][disabled]:active,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:focus,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:hover {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
}
```

If you need the green color, add the following:

```
/* Green */
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color:#5cb85c;
    border-color:#4cae4c;
    color:#fff;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:hover, {
    background-color:#449d44;
    border-color:#398439;
    color:#fff;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active {
    background-image: none;
}
input[type="button"][disabled],
input[type="button"][disabled]:active,
input[type="button"][disabled]:focus,
input[type="button"][disabled]:hover,
input[type="submit"][disabled],
input[type="submit"][disabled]:active,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:focus,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:hover {
    background-color:#5cb85c;
    border-color:#4cae4c;
}
```

If you need the light blue color, use the following:

```
/* Light Blue */
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color:#5bc0de;
    border-color:#46b8da;
    color:#fff;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:hover, {
    background-color:#31b0d5;
    border-color:#269abc;
    color:#fff;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active {
    background-image: none;
}
input[type="button"][disabled],
input[type="button"][disabled]:active,
input[type="button"][disabled]:focus,
input[type="button"][disabled]:hover,
input[type="submit"][disabled],
input[type="submit"][disabled]:active,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:focus,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:hover {
    background-color:#5bc0de;
    border-color:#46b8da;
}
```

If you need the orange color, use the following:

```
/* Orange */
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color:#f0ad4e;
    border-color:#eea236;
    color:#fff;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:hover, {
    background-color:#ec971f;
    border-color:#d58512;
    color:#fff;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active {
    background-image: none;
}
input[type="button"][disabled],
input[type="button"][disabled]:active,
input[type="button"][disabled]:focus,
input[type="button"][disabled]:hover,
input[type="submit"][disabled],
input[type="submit"][disabled]:active,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:focus,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:hover {
    background-color:#f0ad4e;
    border-color:#eea236;
}
```

If you need the red color, use the following:

```
/* Red */
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"] {
    background-color:#d9534f;
    border-color:#d43f3a;
    color:#fff;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:hover, {
    background-color:#c9302c;
    border-color:#ac2925;
    color:#fff;
}
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active {
    background-image: none;
}
input[type="button"][disabled],
input[type="button"][disabled]:active,
input[type="button"][disabled]:focus,
input[type="button"][disabled]:hover,
input[type="submit"][disabled],
input[type="submit"][disabled]:active,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:focus,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:hover {
    background-color:#d9534f;
    border-color:#d43f3a;
}
```